# logout issue using Skydrive API in iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, onedrive

I am integrating application with sky drive API,I am trying to show Login screen of sky drive when user press on Logout.I called logout API for sky drive but after logout how can i clear the session and how to show sky drive login screen,Please help me,
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a great documentation of `Sky Drive` from Microsoft [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/live/hh826521).

You should refer to this [code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/live/hh826543#objective_c) for user sign In.

For Logout refer [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/live/hh913564.aspx)
 , [here also](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/live/hh846824.aspx), [and here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/live/hh913563.aspx).

There are hardly API released without documentation. So kindly refer those first. Hope that helps.